# mapreduce with sort on inner document mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a quick question on map-reduce with mongodb. I have this following document structure

```
{
   "_id": "ffc74819-c844-4d61-8657-b6ab09617271",
   "value": {
     "mid_tag": {
       "0": {
         "0": "Prakash Javadekar",
         "1": "Shastri Bhawan",
         "2": "Prime Minister's Office (PMO)",
         "3": "Narendra Modi"
      },
       "1": {
         "0": "explosion",
         "1": "GAIL",
         "2": "Andhra Pradesh",
         "3": "N Chandrababu Naidu"
      },
       "2": {
         "0": "Prime Minister",
         "1": "Narendra Modi",
         "2": "Bharatiya Janata Party (BJP)",
         "3": "Government"
      }
    },
     "total": 3
  }
}
```

when I am doing my map reduce code on this collection of documents I want to specify total as the sort field in this command

```
db.ana_mid_big.mapReduce(map, reduce, 
        {
            out: "analysis_result",
            sort: {"value.total": -1}
        }
);
```

But this does not seem to work. How can I specify a key which is nested for sorting? Please help.

----------------------- EDIT ---------------------------------

as per the comments I am posting my whole problem here. I have started with a collection with a little more than 3.5M documents (this is just an old snap shot of the live one, which already crossed 5.5 M) which looks like this

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("53b394d6f9c747e33d19234d"),
   "autoUid": "ffc74819-c844-4d61-8657-b6ab09617271"
   "createDate": ISODate("2014-07-02T05:12:54.171Z"),
   "account_details": {
     "tag_cloud": {
       "0": "FIFA World Cup 2014",
       "1": "Brazil",
       "2": "Football",
       "3": "Argentina",
       "4": "Belgium"
    }
  }
}
```

So, there can be many documents with the same autoUid but with different (or partially same or even same) tag_cloud.

I have written this following map-reduce to generate an intermediate collection which looks like the one at the start of the question. So, evidently that is collection of all the tag_clouds belongs to one person in a single document. To achieve this the MR code i used looks like the following

```
var map = function(){

  final_val = {
        tag_cloud: this.account_details.tag_cloud,
        total: 1
  };
  emit(this.autoUid, final_val)
}

var reduce = function(key, values){
  var fv = {
        mid_tags: [],
        total: 0
  }
  try{
    for (i in values){
      fv.mid_tags.push(values[i].tag_cloud);
      fv.total = fv.total + 1;
    }
  }catch(e){
    fv.mid_tags.push(values)
    fv.total = fv.total + 1;
  }
  return fv;
}

db.my_orig_collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, 
        {
            out: "analysis_mid",
            sort: {createDate: -1}
    }
);
```

Here comes problem Number-1 when somebody has more than one record it obeys reduce function. But when somebody has only one instead of naming it "mid_tag" it retains the name "tag_cloud". I understand that there is some problem with the reduce code but can not find what.

Now I want to reach to a final result which looks like

```
{"_id": "ffc74819-c844-4d61-8657-b6ab09617271",
"value": {
    "tags": {
        "Prakash Javadekar": 1,
        "Shastri Bhawan": 1,
        "Prime Minister's Office (PMO)": 1,
        "Narendra Modi": 2,
        "explosion": 1,
        "GAIL": 1,
        "Andhra Pradesh": 1,
        "N Chandrababu Naidu": 1,
        "Prime Minister": 1,
        "Bharatiya Janata Party (BJP)": 1,
        "Government": 1
    }
}
```

Which is finally one document for each person representing the tag density they have used. The MR code I am trying to use (not tested yet) looks like this---

```
var map = function(){
  var val = {};
  if ("mid_tags" in this.value){
    for (i in this.value.mid_tags){
        for (j in this.value.mid_tags[i]){
            k = this.value.mid_tags[i][j].trim();
            if (!(k in val)){
                val[k] = 1;
            }else{
                val[k] = val[k] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    var final_val = {
        tag: val,
        total: this.value.total
    }
    emit(this._id, final_val);
  }else if("tag_cloud" in this.value){
    for (i in this.value.tag_cloud){
        k = this.value.tag_cloud[i].trim();
        if (!(k in val)){
            val[k] = 1;
        }else{
            val[k] = val[k] + 1;
        }
    }
    var final_val = {
        tag: val,
        total: this.value.total
    }
    emit(this._id, final_val);  
  }
}
var reduce = function(key, values){
    return values;
}

db.analysis_mid.mapReduce(map, reduce, 
        {
            out: "analysis_result"
        }
);
```

This last piece of code is not tested yet. That is all I want to do. Please help

Comment: mapReduce sorts on the "key" values only. You cannot sort output without "outputting" to another collection (as you have) and then doing your next `.find()` operation on that collection with a `.sort()` modifier. Perhaps you should show "what you are actually trying to do" in the "mapReduce" operation. This actually leaves your question open to interpretation on "better ways to do this". Currently though the answer is, You cannot sort output with mapReduce.

Comment: Yup. Please specify your map and reduce functions.

Comment: More specifically, note that the `sort` option for [`mapReduce()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) only applies to the *input* documents, not the result values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP background appears to be showing. The data structures you are representing are not showing arrays in typical JSON notation, however there are noted calls to "push" in your mapReduce code that at least in your "interim document" the values are actually arrays. You seem to have "notated" them the same way so it seems reasonable to presume they are.

Actual arrays are your best option for storage here, especially considering your desired outcome. So even if they do not, your original documents should look like this, as they would be represented in the shell:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("53b394d6f9c747e33d19234d"),
   "autoUid": "ffc74819-c844-4d61-8657-b6ab09617271"
   "createDate": ISODate("2014-07-02T05:12:54.171Z"),
   "account_details": {
     "tag_cloud": [
       "FIFA World Cup 2014",
       "Brazil",
       "Football",
       "Argentina",
       "Belgium"
     ]
   }
}
```

With documents like that or if you change them to be like that, then your right tool for doing this is the aggregation framework. That works in native code and does not require JavaScript interpretation, hence it is much faster.

An aggregation statement to get to your final result is like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Unwind the array to "de-normalize"
    { "$unwind": "$account_details.tag_cloud" },

    // Group by "autoUid" and "tag", summing totals
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "autoUid": "$autoUid",
            "tag": "$account_details.tag_cloud"                
        },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},

    // Sort the results to largest count per user
    { "$sort": { "_id.autoUid": 1, "total": -1 }

    // Group to a single user with an array of "tags" if you must
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.autoUid",
        "tags": { 
            "$push": {
                "tag": "$_id.tag",
                "total": "$total"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Slightly different output, but much simpler to process and much faster:

```
{
    "_id": "ffc74819-c844-4d61-8657-b6ab09617271",
    "tags": [
        { "tag": "Narendra Modi", "total": 2 },
        { "tag": "Prakash Javadekar", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "Shastri Bhawan", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "Prime Minister's Office (PMO)", "total": 1 },  
        { "tag": "explosion", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "GAIL", "total":  1 },
        { "tag": "Andhra Pradesh", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "N Chandrababu Naidu", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "Prime Minister", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "Bharatiya Janata Party (BJP)", "total": 1 },
        { "tag": "Government", "total": 1 }
    ]
}
```

Also sorted by "tag relevance score" for the user for good measure, but you can look at dropping that or even both of the last stages as is appropriate to your actual case.

Still, by far the best option. Get to learn how to use the aggregation framework. If your "output" will still be "big" ( over 16MB ) then try to look at moving to MongoDB 2.6 or greater. Aggregate statements can produce a "cursor" which can be iterated rather than pull all results at once. Also there is the **`$out`** operator which can create a collection just like mapReduce does.

---

If your data is actually in the "hash" like format of sub-documents how you indicate in your notation of this ( which follows a PHP "dump" convention for arrays ), then you need to use mapReduce as the aggregation framework cannot traverse "hash-keys" the way these are represented. Not the best structure, and you should change it if this is the case.

Still there are several corrections to your approach and this does in fact become a single step operation to the final result. Again though, the final output will contain and "array" of "tags", since it really is not good practice to use your "data" as "key" names:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {

        var tag_cloud = this.account_details.tag_cloud; 
        var obj = {};

        for ( var k in tag_cloud ) {
            obj[tag_cloud[k]] = 1; 
        }

        emit( this.autoUid, obj );

    },
    function(key,values) {

        var reduced = {};

        // Combine keys and totals
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            for ( var k in value ) {
                if (!reduced.hasOwnProperty(k))
                    reduced[k] = 0;
                reduced[k] += value[k];
            }
        });

        return reduced;
    },
    { 
        "out": { "inline": 1 }, 
        "finalize": function(key,value) {

            var output = [];

            // Mapped to array for output
            for ( var k in value ) {
                output.push({
                    "tag": k,
                    "total": value[k]
                });                    
            }

            // Even sorted just the same
            return output.sort(function(a,b) {
                return ( a.total < b.total ) ? -1 : ( a.total > b.total ) ? 1 : 0;
            });

        }
    }
)
```

Or if it actually is an "array" of "tags" in your original document but your end output will be too big and you cannot move up to a recent release, then the initial array processing is just a little different:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {

        var tag_cloud = this.account_details.tag_cloud; 
        var obj = {};

        tag_cloud.forEach(function(tag) {
            obj[tag] = 1; 
        });

        emit( this.autoUid, obj );

    },
    function(key,values) {

        var reduced = {};

        // Combine keys and totals
        values.forEach(function(value) {
            for ( var k in value ) {
                if (!reduced.hasOwnProperty(k))
                    reduced[k] = 0;
                reduced[k] += value[k];
            }
        });

        return reduced;
    },
    { 
        "out": { "replace": "newcollection" },
        "finalize": function(key,value) {

            var output = [];

            // Mapped to array for output
            for ( var k in value ) {
                output.push({
                    "tag": k,
                    "total": value[k]
                });                    
            }

            // Even sorted just the same
            return output.sort(function(a,b) {
                return ( a.total < b.total ) ? -1 : ( a.total > b.total ) ? 1 : 0;
            });

        }
    }
)
```

Everything essentially follows the same principles to get to the end result:

1. De-normalize to a "user" and "tag" combination with "user" and the grouping key
2. Combine the results per user with a total on "tag" values.

In the mapReduce approach here, apart from being cleaner than what you seemed to be trying, the other main point to consider here is that the reducer needs to "output" **exactly** the same sort of "input" that comes from the mapper. The reason is actually well documented, as the "reducer" can in fact get called several times, basically "reducing again" output that has already been through reduce processing.

This is generally how mapReduce deals with "large inputs", where there are lots of values for a given "key" and the "reducer" only processes so many of them at one time. For example a reducer may actually only take 30 or so documents emitted with the same key, reduce two sets of those 30 down to 2 documents and then finally reduce to a single output for a single key.

---

The end result here is the same as the other output shown above, with the mapReduce difference that everything is under a "value" key as that is just how it works.

So a couple of ways to do it depending on your data. Do try to stick with the aggregation framework where possible as it is much faster and modern versions can consume and output just as much data as you can throw at mapReduce.

Comment: Such a beautifully written insightful answer. I am glad to read this. This actually resolved a lot of confusions in my mind about map-reduce and aggregation framework. Thank you very much

Comment: Just to add that, the format i pasted here were taken from rockmongo and thus it was looking like this. It is actually a []